# PHP PDO Connection to SQL Server with integrated security?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Can I connect to SQL Server 2008 using PDO and integrated security using the mssql driver? Currently doing something like this to connect normally:

```
$db = new PDO("mssql:host=host;dbname=db", "user", "pass");
```

This works fine using SQL Server authentication, but it is a pain having to create SQL server logins for loads of databases, so it would be nice to use integrated security if possible. I am running PHP as CLI on Windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This site helped:
[SQL Server Driver for PHP: Understanding Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brian_swan/sql-server-driver-for-php-understanding-windows-authentication)

The gist of it that fixed my issue was:

- Enable Windows Authentication
- Disable Anonymous Authentication
- remove the username and password from the PDO connection

```php
$conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=$dbName" );
```

My testing was with the newest driver released June 2010 (SQL Server Driver for PHP 2.0 CTP2).