# Connecting to MSSQL Server 2005 using PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo, timeout, sqlsrv

I'm trying to establish a connection with PHP and MS SQL Server 2005. I'm using IIS 8 in Windows 8 and PHP version 5.3.28. I already done my research, I've found MSSQL PHP PDO (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff754357(v=sql.105).aspx), downloaded and enabled all of PDO related DLLs I've found from Microsoft website (Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server) and assured they are reflecting in phpinfo().

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_52_nts_vc6.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc6.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll
```

The following links in Stock Over Flow also helped me alot in my dilemma:

- [Connect to SQL Server through PDO using SQL Server Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747554/connect-to-sql-server-through-pdo-using-sql-server-driver)
- [Error connecting to MSSQL with SQLSrv and PHP 5.4.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651646/error-connecting-to-mssql-with-sqlsrv-and-php-5-4-7)
- [How can I connect to Sql Server from a Mac with PHP PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371281/how-can-i-connect-to-sql-server-from-a-mac-with-php-pdo)
- [Connecting to mssql using pdo through php and linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953882/connecting-to-mssql-using-pdo-through-php-and-linux)

I'm able to fix the "driver not found" and "connection string is invalid" issues, and here's my current PHP codes:

```
$db_server = "func.website.com,8787";
//$db_server = "func.website.com:8787\sqlexpress";
$db_database = "db_BreadNButter";
$db_user = "tinapay";
$db_passwd = "p@ssword";

try {
   //$db = new PDO ("mssql:host=$db_server;dbname=$db_database;", $db_user, $db_passwd);
   $db = new PDO ("sqlsrv:Server=$db_server;Database=$db_database;", $db_user, $db_passwd);
} catch(PDOException $exception) {
   die("Unable to open database.<br>Error message:<br><br>$exception.");
}
```

I think (fingers-crossed) that I already established a connection to MSSQL DBase, but I'm getting the error below:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08001]:
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: Timeout error [258].
' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\breadnbutter\class.connection.php:12 Stack trace: #0
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\breadnbutter\class.connection.php(12):
PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=f...', 'tinapay', 'p@ssword') #1 {main}.
```

Can anyone enlighten me on why am I getting timeout errors and how can I fix this?

Comment: from my experience trying to connect to MSSQL I ended up using php_odbc - if you don't have to use PDO maybe try that

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not allowed to use ODBC... It's a shame though... I know it's much easier if I do that.

Comment: also I remember that I couldn't use prefix dbo_ before table names - I was pulling my hair out until found out about that - after I removed that everything worked fine

Comment: Anyways, I really need help in making this work. I really do appreciate those people helping me out here. I'm still kinda stuck...

Comment: I've tried to revised my code and tried to display something:

`try {
    $dbh = new PDO ("sqlsrv:Server=$db_server;Database=$db_database;", $db_user, $db_passwd);
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from dbo.BGCountry') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}`

I'm still getting the same error:

`SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: Timeout error [258]`

Comment: try to isolate the code and debug in smaller chunks; dump `$dbh` and see if you get PDO object; from my experience `SQLSTATE[08001` is quite broad in terms of when it gets thrown

Comment: also I see that you use `dbo` prefix before table name - try without it as this is where I got stuck and after removing this it worked fine

Comment: how should i dump it?

Comment: `var_dump`, `print_r` or `var_export` whatever suit your needs - you need to check what is in `$dbh` after PDO constructor has been invoked

Answer (score 1):

The port should be `func.website.com:8787`. You have a typo with the comma.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried that already and that gives me the error  `[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]` – that's why I used comma(,) instead of colon (:)

Answer (score 1):

how to connect sqlsrv 2008 in php 5.4.4
erro is:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => IMSSP
            [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP
            [1] => -49
            [code] => -49
            [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
            [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => IM002
        [SQLSTATE] => IM002
        [1] => 0
        [code] => 0
        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
        [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    )
```

)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still having problems with this, but I'm able to convince my boss to use asp instead of PHP. thanks a lot for those who helped me out.