# Cannot connect to SQL Server using PHP and Windows Authentication

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

I have a requirement to connect to a local SQL Server using PHP and Windows Authentication (specifying a username and password is not an option; it must be via Windows Authentication only).

Here is the connection string as per the Microsoft examples:

```
try {   
   $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Database=accounting;ConnectionPooling=0", NULL, NULL);   
   $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
}
```

Here is the error message that I am receiving:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\server$'. in ...
```

However I had already added this computer to the access on the SQL Server using these commands:

```
CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN\server$] FROM WINDOWS;
GO
USE accounting;
GO
CREATE USER [DOMAIN\server$] FROM LOGIN [DOMAIN\server$];
GO
```

What else could be the issue?

Comment: `(specifying a username and password is not an option; it must be via Windows Authentication only).` Why? setting up a dedicated SQL account for that database is easy to do, easy to maintain. Windows authentication is a PAIN.

Comment: @Tschallacka Best practice is to use a AD account.  Windows Authentication Mode in SQL Server can leverage the organization-wide Active Directory, account, group and password policies, thereby making access more secure.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857194/php-pdo-connection-to-sql-server-with-integrated-security

Comment: @Oscar I am already not supplying a username and password in the connection string, which is what that answer suggests to do.

Comment: @Tschallacka This question is more of why it is showing that error message when I've added the permissions, rather than why we want to do it as we do.

Comment: I don't have any clue about WINdows auth but the error says soemthing with a server$ ...Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\server$'. is that what you want or shouldn't this be something like Login failed for user 'MY_NICE_DOMAIN\the_best_server_ever' ???

Comment: @AlexOdenthal Obviously I am using place holders rather than the company and server as that could be a security risk :-)

Comment: May be it's related to this article: [Only Windows Auth allowed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29992/odbc-data-source-sql-server-connection-login-failed-for-user)

Comment: Check sql server error log to find out the cause. It's the next row to 18456 error

Comment: ...And where is trusted connection in your connection string? I see no Integrated Security=true, nieghter Trusted_Connection=True

Comment: There is no such option in PDO and it is not required. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-connect-using-windows-authentication. It uses Windows Authentication by default, when no username and password is specified. Please state correct information only.

Comment: @Jack my comment is related to the server side. not the PDO Driver or something. If you connect to using Windows auth by default and the server doesn't accept this...well.